# Converting SQL varbinary to image and receiving parameter is not valid

Tags: c#

I am attempting to pull data from SQL and display it into a picturebox on the windows form.

The code:

```
// Use the customer number to obtain image from the DBFile table
Query.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM DBFile " +
    "WHERE " +
    "FileName = @FileName";

// Fill in the parameters
Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", customerNumber + ".jpg");

// Build the DBFile data table
da = new SqlDataAdapter(Query);
cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.Fill(DBFile);

// Dispose of SQL data
da.Dispose();
cb.Dispose();
Query.Dispose();

try
{
    byte[] bImage = new byte[0];
    bImage = (byte[])DBFile.Rows[0]["Data"];
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bImage);
    pbLicense.Image = Image.FromStream(ms); // Error is thrown here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

My question is, is this the proper way of not only obtaining the data needed but also converting it into the desired outcome and if so, what am I missing?. I have looked at many tutorials and guides but all seem to similar in the regard that I am attempting.

Comment: what is the error thrown? And why is byte array's size 0?

Comment: Parameter is not valid.
The byte array gets filled in the following line--I have played with that number as well but to no avail.

Comment: Your code has other problems: 1) Don't use `ex.Message` - it leaves out important information. 2) Your `SqlDataAdapter`, `MemoryStream`, and maybe more, should be in `using` blocks, so that they will still be disposed if an exception occurs.

Comment: How did you get the image bytes *into* the database? If you saved the wrong thing, you could be loading the wrong thing.

Comment: The database is already created with said data already in it--I am trying to pull and convert from it. The only details I have pertaining to the database, more specefically the table and matching column is the datatype: varbinary(max).

Comment: The ParamName is null -- this is where the error is, I assume?